# Python Selenium List Comprehension not Iterating

Tags: python, selenium, list-comprehension

When I run this, everything works up until the point right at the bottom of the code where I use list comprehension to iterate through a list of WebElements. When I print the variable `stonk_data`, I get a list of the same length as `all_stonks`, but every element is a repeat of the first index of `all_stonks`.

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

investing_url = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/united-states'

def get_driver():
    ffox_options = Options()
    #ffox_options.add_argument('--headless')
    s = Service('/home/l/geckodriver')
    driver = Firefox(service=s, options=ffox_options)
    return driver

def get_stonks(driver):
    driver.get(investing_url)
    stonks_filter = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stocksFilter')
    return stonks_filter

def select_all_us_stonks(driver):
    stonks_page_filter = get_stonks(driver)
    action.move_to_element(stonks_page_filter).perform()
    action.click(on_element=stonks_page_filter).perform()
    action.send_keys_to_element(stonks_page_filter, Keys.UP).perform()
    action.send_keys_to_element(stonks_page_filter, Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(10)

def get_all_stonks(driver):
    #stonks_table_container = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'marketInnerContent')
    stonks_table_selector = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'marketInnerContent')
    stonks_table = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
    stonks_table_body = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
    stonks_table_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')
    stonks_table_rows_data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tr/td')
    stonks_table_rows_namelink = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tr/td[2]')
    return stonks_table_rows_namelink


def pull_all_stonks(stonk):
    stonks_table_name_and_link = stonk.find_element(By.XPATH, '//tr/td[2]/a')
    stonk_name = stonks_table_name_and_link.text
    stonk_link = stonks_table_name_and_link.get_attribute('href')

    return {
        'stonk_name': stonk_name,
        'stonk_link': stonk_link
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = get_driver()
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    select_all_us_stonks(driver)


    all_stonks = get_all_stonks(driver)
    print(f'Pulling {len(all_stonks)} stonks')
    print(all_stonks)


    #the list comprehension in question
    stonk_data = [pull_all_stonks(stonk) for stonk in all_stonks]



    print(stonk_data)
```

Comment: Use .// when xpathing otherwise you end up with the first element.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Also it seems your trying to xpath to a tr from inside a tr.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to see what went wrong with your code, I just modified both functions pull_all_stonks and get_all_stonks.

```
def pull_all_stonks(stonk):
    stonk_name, stonk_link = (this_stonk:=stonk.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[1]).text, this_stonk.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute("href")

def get_all_stonks(driver):
    stonks = []
    for stonk in driver.find_element_by_id("cross_rate_markets_stocks_1").find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
        stonks.append(stonk)
    return stonks
```

which now returns

```
{'stonk_name': 'Ford Motor', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/ford-motor-co'}
{'stonk_name': 'Apple', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc'}
{'stonk_name': 'Ascent Solar', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/ascent-solar-tech'}
{'stonk_name': 'Bank of America', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/bank-of-america'}
{'stonk_name': 'AT&T', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/at-t'}
{'stonk_name': 'AMD', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/adv-micro-device'}
{'stonk_name': 'NVIDIA', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/nvidia-corp'}
{'stonk_name': 'Marvell', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/marvell-technology-group-ltd'}
{'stonk_name': 'Petroleo Brasileiro Petrobras ADR', 'stonk_link': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/petroleo-bras'}
#etc...
```